# Python - (SSH/Telnet) connection with multiple commands

Tags: linux, ssh, automation, telnet

I need to run a shell script that should interact with couple of servers / routers in daily schedule. The script will simply login to the remote end, run a command. Up to here i hear that you are saying it is easy. The real problem here is that i need to analyze the output of the first command and based on the output i need to organize the second command. This is also doable, but the situation here is that i do not want to login and logout from the box for every command.

What i need is to login once, stay alive ,run the command take the output, analyze it and then run the second command later on logout and close connection.

Correct me if i am wrong but expect is not an option here. I want to ask for your suggestions.

Which language / module of this language i can use to complete this requirement. 
Environment is not pure ssh, so i should have something general that can be used for both ssh/telnet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is pretty broad.  I suggest looking at `expect` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) or similar.

Comment: Expect is not helping me here as i need some high level language support as well. During the interactions i supposed to analyze data. Expect will not be capable to do that analyze.

Answer (score -1):

Since you mentioned python, pexpect should do the job pretty well:
https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html